# Docker data-root directory permissions

Tags: docker

In our docker installations we set the docker parameter "data-root" to change the data root dir, and we point it to a dir with permissions 755.
The problem is that a every start/restart of the docker service, the permissions are automatically changed to 710

Is it possible to change this behaviour, and make the 755 the def. permissions?
Thanks

Comment: Nothing in the Docker directory is intended to be directly usable; why do the permissions matter?  (Is this a question about programming or more system administration?)

Comment: @DavidMaze system administration.

Comment: Stack Overflow is specifically about programming questions; also see the [help/on-topic].  Depending on what you're doing, better places to ask could include [sf], [unix.se], or [devops.se].

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution by adding an ExecStartPost command to the docker systemd service file:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 775 /path/to/dir
```